# Is it possible to disable c++ assert from .net app

Tags: c#, c++

I have the following problem:
I use c++ library from my WPF app, the library throws an assertion in some very rare cases. It shows a nice dialog with c++ filename, the line number and assert expression. So the question is: can I disable asserts in the c++ library assuming that I don't have source code. What I really need is to "catch" this assertion and log it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it triggering an assertion or throwing an exception?

Comment: it is an assertion. Exception is not a problem

Answer (score 4):

One way is to create a thread that performs `EnumWindows` every so often and detects if an assert window pops up, it can then capture the message and click the ignore button. This will still cause the window to show up for a short while (depending on your interval between `EnumWindows` but I assume you customers aren't going to be getting the debug DLL so it shouldn't matter.

---

Another option is calling [`_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, 0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y71x448.aspx) to disable asserts from being shown altogether. 
If you want to PInvoke this from .NET note that `_CRT_ASSERT` is equal to 2.

Comment: The problem is the dll was developed by another team and it asserts in release mode :) that is why I'm looking for any way to stop it.

Comment: @Alex, I've added another option which I think will better suite your needs.

Comment: Motti, thanks for the idea. I gave it a try it does not work. I guess assertion is caused by assert macros, but your solution works with _ASSERT one. It seems that assert macro just popups a dialog box with the assertion message :(

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your assembler skills and whether steps have been taken deliberately to block this type of stuff, it's usually possible to modify binary code to prevent this sort of message being displayed.

However, an assertion firing is often a precursor to some more spectacular crash or other misbehaviour, so just stopping the message box might not get you much further.   Of course, some assertions are buggy, so this might be all you need.

If I had to modify this DLL, I would disassemble it with IDA and work out a patch.  Hiding the assertion would probably be fairly easy, logging it quite a lot harder.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to fix some old code which relied on a DLL which sometimes popped up an assert message. I tried all the above suggestions, and the only one which I got working was to click on the Ignore button. The user above suggested running EnumWindows on a separate thread - I used FindWindow instead.

This is the function which finds the Assert popup message, finds the Ignore button within there, and then clicks it. It goes on a loop which checks a global variable each time (ugly but quick):

```
void CloseAssertBox (void *param) {
  HWND window, button;
  Sleep (200); //wait 200 milliseconds
  while (!finishThread) { //see if we can stop checking
    if ((window = FindWindow (NULL, L"Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library"))
        && (button = FindWindowEx (window, NULL, L"Button", L"&Ignore")))
        SendMessage (button, BM_CLICK, 0, 0); //click the button
    Sleep (50); //then check every 50 milliseconds
  }
}
```

The title of your Assert box might be different. If your Ignore button is referenced differently, you can use EnumChildWindows to get the name of each child control including buttons.

Before the bit of code which pops up the assert, I start a new thread which calls the function above.

```
finishThread = 0; //this is set to 1 when the thread should finish
_beginthread (CloseAssertBox, 0, NULL); //begin the thread
```

After making it through the dangerous assert-prone code, I set:

```
finishThread = 1; //done threaded stuff
```

That way the thread will close next time round its loop. There's probably better ways of doing that.

I had to include these libraries to make it work:

```
#include <process.h> //for multithreading
#include <WinBase.h> //for Sleep function
int finishThread; //to tell the thread when encoding has finished
```

This was all done in Visual Studio 2010 using a library from 2006.